# Using iOS camera to scan credit card in webView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, credit-card

I can use the `iOS` camera to scan `credit card` details using `Safari`, but when I loaded the same web page in a `UIWebView` it didn't work .
Any suggestions ?

*here is my `HTML` input tag content*

```
    <input name="addCreditCardNumber "
           type="text"
           placeholder="addCreditCardNumber"
           pattern="[0-9]*">
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently available in Safari only. Hope Apple would provide the same in WebView in future. You can use card.io as an alternative for now.